# let me know alternate command in DOS for following unix command

Tags: windows, unix, shell-script

```
find /coe/informatica/v712_OMJ/AONE/SrcFiles/Archive -name *AccessOne_DF_BIFs.txt|cut -f8 -d "/"|cut -c 1-12 > /coe/informatica/v712_OMJ/AONE/TgtFiles/ExtendedAOneWeeklySource/WeeklyDeltaFileLoadIDList.dat
```

please let me know the use of

```
cut -f8 -d and -name *AccessOne_DF_BIFs.txt //this is a file name in unix box
```

Comment: There is no DOS! cmd.exe IS NOT DOS and hasn't been for ages!

Answer (score 6):

Re: the use of "cut -f8 -d" and "find -name"

```
cut -f8 -d "/"
```

That gives you the eight field in a string delimited by "/". So on a string like "a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j" it will give you "h"

```
find /coe/informatica/v712_OMJ/AONE/SrcFiles/Archive -name *AccessOne_DF_BIFs.txt
```

The -name option specifies the pattern to match for. The whole command above will recursively search for all files within the Archive directory that ends with "AccessOne_DF_BIFs.txt"

This is what the whole command does:

- **find /coe/informatica/v712_OMJ/AONE/SrcFiles/Archive -name *AccessOne_DF_BIFs.txt** - recursively look for all "AccessOne_DF_BIFs.txt" files within the Archive directory
- **cut -f8 -d "/"** - From the output of the previous command, extract the eight field delimitted by "/"
- **cut -c 1-12** - Extract only the first 12 characters
- **> /coe/informatica/v712_OMJ/AONE/TgtFiles/ExtendedAOneWeeklySource/WeeklyDeltaFileLoadIDList.dat** - Write out the results into the WeeklyDeltaFileLoadIDList.dat file

Re: Windows replacement

My *DOS-fu* and *PowerShell-fu* is severely lacking, so I can't help you there. However, you can use the same commands on windows if you used [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) or [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys). Do note however that the paths to your files will be different when accessed from within Cygwin/MSYS. If you wish to use windows directory structures (e.g. C:\my\windblows\directory), then you may have a better chance with MSYS.

**~ Update ~**

re: equivalent command in DOS

Had a go during coffee break and this seems to work for me.

DOS-fu:

```
@echo off

:: Source directory
set SRCDIR="C:\coe\informatica\v712_OMJ\AONE\SrcFiles\Archive"
:: Pattern to match
set TARGET="*AccessOne_DF_BIFs.txt"
:: Set output file
set OUTFILE="C:\coe\informatica\v712_OMJ\AONE\TgtFiles\ExtendedAOneWeeklySource\WeeklyDeltaFileLoadIDList.dat"

:: Store current working directory so we can send user back
set PWD=%cd%
:: Move to source directory so our "dir" command will work
cd %SRCDIR%

:: Reset previous output file
del %OUTFILE%

:: This is where the script actually starts
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=8 delims=\" %%a IN (`dir %TARGET% /s/b`) DO (
    set X=%%a
    echo %X:~0,13%
) >> %OUTFILE%

:: Send user back to where he/she was
cd %PWD%
```

Not quite the one-liner that you can get with Unix 'find' and 'cut', but it gets the same job done (I hope) using only built-in DOS directives.

The FOR loop is what does the job. The rest are mostly there to make the script more readable.

Note that "*echo %X:~0,13%*" is not a typo and ought to be equivalent to "*cut -c 1-12*".

I bet there are cleaner and more elegant ways to do it. This was my first attempt at DOS-fu so be nice.

Sources:

- http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm
- http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.MidString

Comment: Minor nitpick: This can't work in DOS. It's specific to the Windows NT command prompt (cmd.exe).

Answer (score 4):

Can you install one of the unix-alike packages such as Cygwin?

Or maybe install a scripting language such as Perl?

Does that command of yours actually work? Maybe missing a -print from the find.

```
 find -name  xxx
```

look for the specified file name

```
 cut -f 8 -d "/"
```

split up into fields delimited by /, take the 8th one

Such things are not so smooth in raw Windows command line, hence the recommendation to install a nicer scripting environment.

Comment: Windows is unusable without cygwin. How can someone survive with the powerful shell-tools. I personally didn't switched to Linux for years (I did it after XP), but since long time I used cygwin, very important tool. The link is http://cygwin.com/

Answer (score 3):

To substitute cut type in DOS command "help for"

look at syntax:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in (myfile.txt) do @echo %i %j %k
```

instead (myfile.txt) specify *AccessOne_DF_BIFs.txt

to make it recursive use loop

Answer (score 2):

You can find a port of common Unix utilities [here on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/) (including find and cut).

There is not out-of-the-box way to do this on Windows that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

for ports of *nix tools to windows, use the ones from [GNU](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about these particular commands but this is my reference for commands : http://ss64.com/